# Remove indent of first paragraph when using titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec

I use the `titlesec` to format section in `book` class. The section pos to leftmargin, but when I compiled, the firs paragraph have indent. How to remove indent automatically.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont\vspace{12pt}
    \titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}%
    \vspace{6pt}%
    \sffamily\bfseries\filleft}
{\thesection\\}{.5em}{}[]
\titlespacing{\section}{7pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the starred version of `\titlespacing`.

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{7pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont\vspace{12pt}
    \titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}%
    \vspace{6pt}%
    \sffamily\bfseries\filleft}
{\thesection\\}{.5em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{7pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section here}
  Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
\end{document}
```

[image]